# WebGL Texture image Flip

Tags: webgl

How to flip the image in webGL?
[image]

The original image is:
[image]

I do not have idea at this moment

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few ideas:

1. Change the UV coordinates on your triangle
2. Flip the UV coordinates in your shader
3. Change pixel [unpacking in webgl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/pixelStorei)
4. Apply the desired image operations with a 2D canvas and upload that

Answer (score 0):

My example which shows how to load a texture:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Load Texture</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="renderCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec2 aPosition;
        attribute vec2 aTexCoord;
        uniform mat4 uMvpMatrix;
        varying vec2 vTexCoord;
        void main() {
            gl_Position = uMvpMatrix * vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
            vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        uniform sampler2D uSampler;
        varying vec2 vTexCoord;
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTexCoord);
        }
    </script>

    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gl-matrix@3.4.3"
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="module">
        import { mat4 } from "gl-matrix";

        const gl = document.getElementById("renderCanvas")
            .getContext("webgl", { alpha: false, premultipliedAlpha: false });
        gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
        gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

        function loadTexture(url) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                const image = new Image();
                image.onload = () => {
                    const texture = gl.createTexture();
                    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
                    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
                    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
                    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
                    resolve(texture);
                };
                image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
                image.src = url;
            });
        }

        async function main() {
            const vertShaderSrc = document.getElementById("vertexShader").firstChild.textContent;
            const vShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vShader, vertShaderSrc);
            gl.compileShader(vShader);

            const fragShaderSrc = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").firstChild.textContent;
            const fShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fShader, fragShaderSrc);
            gl.compileShader(fShader);

            const program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program, vShader);
            gl.attachShader(program, fShader);
            gl.linkProgram(program);
            gl.useProgram(program);

            const vertPositions = [
                -0.5, -0.5,
                0.5, -0.5,
                -0.5, 0.5,
                0.5, 0.5
            ];
            const vertPosBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertPosBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertPositions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            const aPositionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);

            const texCoords = [
                0, 0,
                1, 0,
                0, 1,
                1,1
            ];
            const texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(texCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            const aTexCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aTexCoord");
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(aTexCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aTexCoordLocation);

            const texture = await loadTexture("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nxvziah1a7n9txd/256px-WebGL_Logo.svg.png");

            const projMatrix = mat4.create();
            mat4.ortho(projMatrix, -50, 50, -50, 50, 50, -50);

            const viewMatrix = mat4.create();
            mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix, [0, 0, 50], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);

            const projViewMatrix = mat4.create();
            mat4.mul(projViewMatrix, projMatrix, viewMatrix);

            const modelMatrix = mat4.create();
            mat4.scale(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, [100, 50, 1]);

            const mvpMatrix = mat4.create();
            mat4.mul(mvpMatrix, projViewMatrix, modelMatrix);

            const uMvpMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uMvpMatrix");

            gl.clearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uMvpMatrixLocation, false, mvpMatrix);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        }
        main();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```